# How to setup exim/dovecot for emailing groups?

Tags: dovecot, exim, groups, mailbox

I want to migrate from Axigen to exim/dovecot. Axigen has section named "Groups". So I can create new group, add there few accounts. After when I send email to this group, all members get this message. I don't even know what to Google. I only find mailing lists. But Axigen has mailing lists too and it differ from groups.

So what I should to search for my purpose?

Comment: I am not really familiar with Exim, but I think you want address rewriting. Start at http://www.exim.org/exim-html-3.20/doc/html/spec_34.html#SEC740 (or the corresponding entry in the documentation for your version of Exim).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to look at aliases.  The file `/etc/aliases` can contain a variety of aliases including groups.  These won't have the subscribe/unsubscribe capability that lists usually have.   However, they will have a common definition for all users.

Many email clients allow you to create groups (or list) in the address book. These are personal lists, although if you have a shared LDAP address book, they can be shared.

Comment: Thank you very much! I thought that alias is only one to one relation.